# funcion index en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, function, controller, model

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde utilizo dos tablas de base de datos distintas en una misma vista, la cosa es que no se como enviarle ambos parametros al mismo tiempo por el mismo return, esta era mi idea pero al momento de ejecutar me dice que no encuentra la variable registros, y tiene sentido ya que solo ejecuta el primer return, pero como puedo hacer para ejecutar uno con ambas partes?

Adjunto el codigo de mi controlador:

```
public function index()
    {
        $registros = Registro::all();
        $datoshojas = Datoshoja::all();
        return view('hojaschequeo.hojas5-7.F7-SETCS-ELE-20-L1-01.index')->with('datoshojas',$datoshojas);
        return view('hojaschequeo.hojas5-7.F7-SETCS-ELE-20-L1-01.index')->with('registros',$registros);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui mi solucion, es algo sencillo, pero recien estoy empezando con laravel, aun asi por si alguien se llega a atorar con algo parecido.

Lo que hice es que utilice dos **with** al final para poder manejar ambas formas de datos, a diferencia de mi ejemplo anterior en el cual utilice doble **return** quedandome como el ejemplo a continuacion:

```
public function index()
{
    $registros = Registro::all();
    $datoshojas = Datoshoja::all();
    return view('hojaschequeo.hojas5-7.F7-SETCS-ELE-20-L1-01.index')
    ->with('registros',$registros)
    ->with('datoshojas',$datoshojas);
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona este código. Ten en cuenta que tal vez para ti sea claro lo que hace, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar no sea así. Luego, no olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: listo, ya hice mis correcciones, y gracias por la retroalimentacion.